# Как сделать перенос на новую строку

Tags: python, url

Хочу написать https запрос, который будет отправляться в браузере, необходимо слово LINK перенести на третью строку, как это можно сделать?

Скрин того, что я получаю сейчас при отправке запроса на Telegram:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел бы получить информацию с картинкой, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос который я отправляю: `api.telegram.org/bot1234567890:AAAAJDJDLKeod-5fFEIDK391kFEKldNSLKSA/sendPhoto?chat_id=@example_canel&photo=https://cdn.csgo.com//item/AWP+%7C+Worm+God+%28Field-Tested%29/300.png&caption=AWP%20[LINK](http://www.example.com/)&parse_mode=MarkdownV2`

P. S. в будущем запрос будет отправляться через python requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `%0A` в качестве символа переноса строки. [Перевод строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

```
caption=blabla%0Atext
```

используя `requests` вполне сойдёт `\n`:

```
msg = {'chat_id': 123, 'text': '\n[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1244019)', 'parse_mode': 'Markdown'}
requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot123:AAE/sendMessage', data=msg)
```

Если нужно отключить предпросмотр ссылки используйте `disable_web_page_preview=True`